# How AddClass to body depending on active slider color class in WP Divi theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to customize the `Divi` theme for Wordpress.

In this project: http://dm-wp.com/vins-lelievre/, I'd like to have the logo and the menu color change to white if the active slide background is dark.

I would like to add a class to the body if the new active slide has the class "et_pb_bg_layout_dark".

Function already exists for adding color class to the slider container.

I think what I am missing is the event that makes the script run again to check the condition.

Can I insert the script in the integration field of the theme or shall I edit theme .js file?

- Probably http://dm-wp.com/vins-lelievre/wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/scripts/frontend-builder-scripts.js?ver=3.0.10

From my investigations, script would look like this.

I guess it's wrong or not complete:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
       if ( jQuery('#slide-home').hasClass( "et_pb_bg_layout_dark" ) ) {
           jQuery('body').addClass('yourClassName');
       }
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Couldn't you just let the class for the light themed navigation being added when "et_pb_bg_layout_dark" is being added?

Comment: Yes that's what I would like to get, but how?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have `<div id="slide-home"></div>` in your code.

When you click on `button`, if `#slide-home` has class `.et_pb_bg_layout_dark`, the background of body will change

```css
body {
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

body.yourClassName {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide-home" class="et_pb_bg_layout_dark"></div>

<button id="btn">check</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
     
     if ( jQuery('#slide-home').hasClass( "et_pb_bg_layout_dark" ) ) {
           jQuery('body').addClass('yourClassName');
       }
   
     
       
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Morteza, but my event is not a click, it's the slider automatic animation. Condition  if ( jQuery('#slide-home').hasClass( "et_pb_bg_layout_dark" ) ) must be checked on each slider automatic change.

Comment: So, remove `click` event

Answer (score 0):

This is the slider structure, where  'et_pb_bg_layout_light' is actually changed for 'et_pb_bg_layout_dark' inside 'et_pb_slider ' if 'et_pb_slide' has   'et_pb_bg_layout_dark'. Only CSS classes, I added the ID '#home-slide', but theoritically it shouldn't be necessary.

```html
   <div id="home-slide" class="et_pb_module et_pb_slider et_slider_auto et_slider_speed_7000 et_slider_auto_ignore_hover  et_pb_fullwidth_slider_0">
    <div class="et_pb_slides">
     <div class="et_pb_slide et_pb_bg_layout_light et_pb_slider_with_text_overlay et_pb_slide_0 et-pb-active-slide" style='background-color:#ffffff;background-image:url(http://dm-wp.com/vins-lelievre/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/léquipe-des-vins-lelievre.jpg);'>
    
    
    <div class="et_pb_container clearfix">
     
     <div class="et_pb_slide_description">
      <h2 class="et_pb_slide_title"><a href="http://dm-wp.com/vins-lelievre/maison-lelievre/">DÉCOUVREZ LA MAISON LELIÈVRE</a></h2>
      <div class="et_pb_slide_content">
<p style="text-align: right;">Une famille, un vignoble, une histoire,<br />
un savoir-faire, des vins&#8230;</p>
</div>
      <a href="http://dm-wp.com/vins-lelievre/maison-lelievre/" class="et_pb_more_button et_pb_button">Découvrir</a>
     </div> <!-- .et_pb_slide_description -->
    </div> <!-- .et_pb_container -->
    
   </div> <!-- .et_pb_slide -->
   <div class="et_pb_slide et_pb_bg_layout_dark et_pb_slider_with_overlay et_pb_slider_with_text_overlay et_pb_slide_1" style='background-color:#ffffff;background-image:url(http://dm-wp.com/vins-lelievre/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/david-lelievre-ca-nous-a-ouvert-des-marches-1433506900.jpg);'>
    
    <div class="et_pb_slide_overlay_container"></div>
    <div class="et_pb_container clearfix">
     
     <div class="et_pb_slide_description">
      <h2 class="et_pb_slide_title"><a href="http://dm-wp.com/vins-lelievre/boutique/">BIENVENUE À LA CAVE</a></h2>
      <div class="et_pb_slide_content">
<p style="text-align: right;">Découvrez nos vins de Lorraine et Côtes de Toul et nos spécialités régionales et internationales.</p>
</div>
      <a href="http://dm-wp.com/vins-lelievre/boutique/" class="et_pb_more_button et_pb_button">Entrer</a>
     </div> <!-- .et_pb_slide_description -->
    </div> <!-- .et_pb_container -->
    
   </div> <!-- .et_pb_slide -->
   <div class="et_pb_slide et_pb_bg_layout_dark et_pb_slider_with_text_overlay et_pb_slide_2" style='background-color:#000000;background-image:url(http://dm-wp.com/vins-lelievre/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/mirabelles-fraiches-1.jpg);'>
    
    
    <div class="et_pb_container clearfix">
     
     <div class="et_pb_slide_description">
      <h2 class="et_pb_slide_title"><a href="http://dm-wp.com/vins-lelievre/categorie-produit/delices-lorrains/mirabelles/mirabelles-fraiches/">ELLES SONT ARRIVÉES!!!</a></h2>
      <div class="et_pb_slide_content">
<p style="text-align: right;">Les mirabelles fraîches 2016 sont là! Venez les chercher ou commandez directement en ligne</p>
</div>
      <a href="http://dm-wp.com/vins-lelievre/categorie-produit/delices-lorrains/mirabelles/mirabelles-fraiches/" class="et_pb_more_button et_pb_button">Acheter</a>
     </div> <!-- .et_pb_slide_description -->
    </div> <!-- .et_pb_container -->
    
   </div> <!-- .et_pb_slide -->
   
    </div> <!-- .et_pb_slides -->
   </div> <!-- .et_pb_slider -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of the original visual builder javascript where I think I can find similar functions to the one I want to have. For example "et_slider_auto_rotate()" or the variable "tabs_animation". Anyone inspired to explain me how it works to get classes checked and added or removed on every slide change?

```html
 window.et_pb_init_modules = function() {
  $.et_pb_simple_slider = function(el, options) {
   var settings = $.extend( {
    slide            : '.et-slide',      // slide class
    arrows     : '.et-pb-slider-arrows',  // arrows container class
    prev_arrow    : '.et-pb-arrow-prev',   // left arrow class
    next_arrow    : '.et-pb-arrow-next',   // right arrow class
    controls     : '.et-pb-controllers a',  // control selector
    carousel_controls   : '.et_pb_carousel_item',  // carousel control selector
    control_active_class : 'et-pb-active-control',  // active control class name
    previous_text   : et_pb_custom.previous,   // previous arrow text
    next_text    : et_pb_custom.next,    // next arrow text
    fade_speed    : 500,       // fade effect speed
    use_arrows    : true,       // use arrows?
    use_controls   : true,       // use controls?
    manual_arrows   : '',       // html code for custom arrows
    append_controls_to  : '',       // controls are appended to the slider element by default, here you can specify the element it should append to
    controls_below   : false,
    controls_class   : 'et-pb-controllers',    // controls container class name
    slideshow    : false,      // automattic animation?
    slideshow_speed   : 7000,       // automattic animation speed
    show_progress_bar  : false,       // show progress bar if automattic animation is active
    tabs_animation   : false,
    use_carousel   : false
   }, options );

   var $et_slider    = $(el),
    $et_slide   = $et_slider.closest_descendent( settings.slide ),
    et_slides_number = $et_slide.length,
    et_fade_speed  = settings.fade_speed,
    et_active_slide  = 0,
    $et_slider_arrows,
    $et_slider_prev,
    $et_slider_next,
    $et_slider_controls,
    $et_slider_carousel_controls,
    et_slider_timer,
    controls_html = '',
    carousel_html = '',
    $progress_bar = null,
    progress_timer_count = 0,
    $et_pb_container = $et_slider.find( '.et_pb_container' ),
    et_pb_container_width = $et_pb_container.width(),
    is_post_slider = $et_slider.hasClass( 'et_pb_post_slider' );

    $et_slider.et_animation_running = false;

    $.data(el, "et_pb_simple_slider", $et_slider);

    $et_slide.eq(0).addClass( 'et-pb-active-slide' );

    if ( ! settings.tabs_animation ) {
     if ( !$et_slider.hasClass('et_pb_bg_layout_dark') && !$et_slider.hasClass('et_pb_bg_layout_light') ) {
      $et_slider.addClass( et_get_bg_layout_color( $et_slide.eq(0) ) );
     }
    }
    


    if ( settings.use_arrows && et_slides_number > 1 ) {
     if ( settings.manual_arrows == '' )
      $et_slider.append( '<div class="et-pb-slider-arrows"><a class="et-pb-arrow-prev" href="#">' + '<span>' +settings.previous_text + '</span>' + '</a><a class="et-pb-arrow-next" href="#">' + '<span>' + settings.next_text + '</span>' + '</a></div>' );
     else
      $et_slider.append( settings.manual_arrows );

     $et_slider_arrows  = $et_slider.find( settings.arrows );
     $et_slider_prev  = $et_slider.find( settings.prev_arrow );
     $et_slider_next  = $et_slider.find( settings.next_arrow );

     $et_slider_next.click( function(){
      if ( $et_slider.et_animation_running ) return false;

      $et_slider.et_slider_move_to( 'next' );

      return false;
     } );

     $et_slider_prev.click( function(){
      if ( $et_slider.et_animation_running ) return false;

      $et_slider.et_slider_move_to( 'previous' );

      return false;
     } );

     // swipe support requires et-jquery-touch-mobile
     $et_slider.find( settings.slide ).on( 'swipeleft', function() {
      $et_slider.et_slider_move_to( 'next' );
     });
     $et_slider.find( settings.slide ).on( 'swiperight', function() {
      $et_slider.et_slider_move_to( 'previous' );
     });
    }

    if ( settings.use_controls && et_slides_number > 1 ) {
     for ( var i = 1; i <= et_slides_number; i++ ) {
      controls_html += '<a href="#"' + ( i == 1 ? ' class="' + settings.control_active_class + '"' : '' ) + '>' + i + '</a>';
     }

     controls_html =
      '<div class="' + settings.controls_class + '">' +
       controls_html +
      '</div>';

     if ( settings.append_controls_to == '' )
      $et_slider.append( controls_html );
     else
      $( settings.append_controls_to ).append( controls_html );

     if ( settings.controls_below )
      $et_slider_controls = $et_slider.parent().find( settings.controls );
     else
      $et_slider_controls = $et_slider.find( settings.controls );

     et_maybe_set_controls_color( $et_slide.eq(0) );

     $et_slider_controls.click( function(){
      if ( $et_slider.et_animation_running ) return false;

      $et_slider.et_slider_move_to( $(this).index() );

      return false;
     } );
    }

    if ( settings.use_carousel && et_slides_number > 1 ) {
     for ( var i = 1; i <= et_slides_number; i++ ) {
      slide_id = i - 1;
      image_src = ( $et_slide.eq(slide_id).data('image') !== undefined ) ? 'url(' + $et_slide.eq(slide_id).data('image') + ')' : 'none';
      carousel_html += '<div class="et_pb_carousel_item ' + ( i == 1 ? settings.control_active_class : '' ) + '" data-slide-id="'+ slide_id +'">' +
       '<div class="et_pb_video_overlay" href="#" style="background-image: ' + image_src + ';">' +
        '<div class="et_pb_video_overlay_hover"><a href="#" class="et_pb_video_play"></a></div>' +
       '</div>' +
      '</div>';
     }

     carousel_html =
      '<div class="et_pb_carousel">' +
      '<div class="et_pb_carousel_items">' +
       carousel_html +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';
     $et_slider.after( carousel_html );

     $et_slider_carousel_controls = $et_slider.siblings('.et_pb_carousel').find( settings.carousel_controls );
     $et_slider_carousel_controls.click( function(){
      if ( $et_slider.et_animation_running ) return false;

      var $this = $(this);
      $et_slider.et_slider_move_to( $this.data('slide-id') );

      return false;
     } );
    }

    if ( settings.slideshow && et_slides_number > 1 ) {
     $et_slider.hover( function() {
      if ( $et_slider.hasClass( 'et_slider_auto_ignore_hover' ) ) {
       return;
      }

      $et_slider.addClass( 'et_slider_hovered' );

      if ( typeof et_slider_timer != 'undefined' ) {
       clearInterval( et_slider_timer );
      }
     }, function() {
      if ( $et_slider.hasClass( 'et_slider_auto_ignore_hover' ) ) {
       return;
      }

      $et_slider.removeClass( 'et_slider_hovered' );

      et_slider_auto_rotate();
     } );
    }

    et_slider_auto_rotate();

    function et_slider_auto_rotate(){
     if ( settings.slideshow && et_slides_number > 1 && ! $et_slider.hasClass( 'et_slider_hovered' ) ) {
      et_slider_timer = setTimeout( function() {
       $et_slider.et_slider_move_to( 'next' );
      }, settings.slideshow_speed );
     }
    }
```